# Find range in a string using Swift 5.7+ Regex

Tags: swift, regex

Here is a legacy way in Swift to search a string for a regular expression and return the range where it was found (or nil if not found):

```
let range = myString.range(of: "\\s*\\d+", options: [.regularExpression])
```

Unfortunately, the regular expression string `"\\s*\\d+"` needs to be compiled at runtime and needs special escaping (for example, `\\s` instead of just `\s`).

How can I upgrade this to use modern [Swift 5.7+ Regex literals](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/regex)? Essentially I want to write something like:

```
let range = myString.range(of: /\s*\d+/)
```

(I do **not** want to use legacy NSRegularExpression methods.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the related method called [firstRange(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/bidirectionalcollection/firstrange(of:)-1di7b)

```
func firstRange(of regex: some RegexComponent) -> Range<Self.Index>?
```

---

```
let range = myString.firstRange(of: /\s*\d+/)
```